# Access interface from parent class

Tags: typescript

I want to access an interface that I, in some way, will define in a child class.

So, for example, if I have this:

```js
export default abstract class MyClass {
    protected foo(arg: this.myInterface): any {
        //
    }
}

export default class FooClass extends MyClass {
    protected myInterface: DataInterface;
}
```

so from the `foo` method defined in the abstract class `MyClass`, the arg will have an `DataInterface` interface.

Is this possible? If not, what's the alternative to this?

-- EDIT

For some context. My Abstract Class will be a `BaseService`, and I will be creating services inheriting from that `BaseService`.

I will be using multiple interfaces and I need to be able to access those interfaces from `BaseService` in order to make sure that the received structure is the correct one.

These structures I want to validate are attributes for a table in a sql server database, so they will be pretty dynamic.

For Example:

```js
export interface IVehicleData {
    vehicle_id?: number;
    vehicle_name?: string;
    vehicle_created_at?: Date;
    vehicle_updated_at?: Date;
  }
```

But in other class, I may have a different interface with different attributes. And also, multiple interfaces, not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wording is a bit confusing because the property `myInterface` in `FooClass` will be an object that fulfills that interface, not a reference to the interface itself.

But this design pattern is fine.  The abstract class needs to know that it has a `myInterface` property.  Presumably in order to do whatever `foo` does on multiple different interfaces, there is some shared base interface?

You can use [generic classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes) so that each class is aware of it's own interface type.  We can say that they all must extend a shared base, and that way the base abstract class can handle functions that depend on the base type while the children can implement behavior that is specific to their interface.

**Edit:**
I Redesigned the code so that it no longer depends on a shared `BaseInterface`.  Instead, the base class can force its children to implement certain methods or have certain properties, and that's how we get to a point where the base class is useful.

```
abstract class MyClass<T> {
    protected rawData: T;

    constructor( myInterface: T ) {
        this.rawData = myInterface;
    }

    protected foo(arg: T): any {
        //
    }

    abstract getId(): number;

    protected doSomethingWithId(): any {
        // base class can use the id but doesn't know or care how getId is implemented
        const id = this.getId();
    }
}

class VehicleClass extends MyClass<IVehicleData> {

    public okMethod( arg: IVehicleData ) {
        this.foo(arg);
    }

    public badMethod( arg: {} ) {
        this.foo(arg);  // error because this.foo can only accept this class's type
    }

    public getId(): number {
        // methods can be implemented based on the specific data type
        return this.rawData.vehicle_id || -1;
    }
}
```

[New Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQEsB2CxwGYEMDGYSAkgGpgAWK%20ANmACK4K5IDeoSnSAbpdXQH0UAEwD8ALiRoArgFsARlgDcHLryq0wAtLllgJSAM4I46AOYqQXHn00D8cMEzDCBTA40yXr6-lulQws6u7pKeYN5IAL6gsSC48sZwBMi0uIaGSACyAJ4AwjTphgA8ACoAfGyqnFBwMJj4mMJIyQDunriSpZbVSPgwaEnSjfAAFEiyOcQYWHiEXUgAlFVW1lwIVIYAdG0dSAC8E1MzOAQRvTEgvbX1YI0uSNgwMKO4cGZdi5K4aDkra1wAPSAi5xawJJIpJBmMAIYjCUZfKRyRRwHqrGp1BpNJDCGAAZRgeg25gA6igNvDEd9fv8AUhgUh5OkiGkMn0fkhpIYiBsiCImdJkHiwIY0AByZAAazQMFaSHgHMcSAocuhsPhqEyKFkUDoehmwl61n6g2QAsOJO2MLhCMWkU4l0uoDZmXIGjoBSKSEgmDQwkyuS9GWKZFsdA6lXYVwxSCg0nkNGoCqlWVhqoRSDeHxI7r8e2W0fpSCtWyeL2z9tBMes8cTyeZwjTGxgmezklYUSWdIBpfLr3e9s4jKwdTgTLuuG5vM2ZeeHLQCrQND%20BEIUGQVr6hQy4syCByUDA1euCaT%20HVtupyIUWB7a0ZxIzmXwnMUqF1%20rAhqZLOaAxLCgiEMI98BQbBkyCZgS0PY9Y2sRwEGkOBF1LXYmFwLZfDsAUAB9cKQABaABGB1olAKIgA)

[Old Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QJLmvJZAbwFgAoZS5GAexoC5kMwpQBzAbnIF9zzRIsRCgAicMHFyCCKCAA9IIACYY0mHHiGFSFKrQZMW7LrspLxcRgCUICGlCUAeZqxBsANMjggAngD4TXjJyOAAjF0QwZAQAG0xVAFkfAGE4jAxHABVkeUUVNSwpfGE-YnIqZAAHKBpIBEglZABbHyKtCEZMk3KqOxAXAFd6%20wAKZtbNGU7kAEoy0wrkMAALYAwAOha2mWQAXnHt4RMKoJ7KatrbBuo6EbgoNk6Zxm8fecWqAHpPs%20Qg07IsXiyAAYnRUsDchBlIkUmkMmIJIckKUdL9KgNQjFgAhkDQANYJCArGhKMb3R7IRGSSbCWbvD5LVYbfR3B4zY5UAEVDFYnHIUJwJREklkrwPRjoQq0whzHSMplrdasikcyjfHJQGpQAW2OADLCKll0aLePEgGJvRBISpRFZraLwgDkqjAPkqEF%20-yAA)

Comment: Apologies for the wording, didn't know how else explain that haha. Can you check the edit? I added more context.

Comment: the thing with your approach is that there's no way that a BaseInterface will serve my purpose since properties are completely different across classes, because of attribute prefixes specific for each table.

Comment: ok I'll edit my reply to remove the `extends BaseInterface`.  In order for the base class to be useful, there has to be some shared interface between the classes BUT the shared interface can be the class itself and not the data structure.  That was an assumption on my part but it's not a necessity.  For example all classes can have a 'getId' method and VehicleClass can implement it by returning an object's vehicle_id while others do differently.

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely closer to what I'm looking for. Already implemented an adaptation of this in my code but now I'm getting errors in the parent class stating that the generic interface doesn't have the attribute I'm accessing to. Do you know what can I do in that case?

Comment: Right so this is what I’m getting at when I say that the parent has to have some amount of knowledge to be useful.  If the generic interface T truly can be anything then it does not make sense for the parent class to interact with the interface directly.   If the attribute that you are trying to access in the parent class does exist in every T, then that is the shared base that T should extend.  If the attribute is a variable, then make sure it must extend keyof T.  If the attribute doesn’t exist in every T, then it shouldn’t be accessed in the parent class.

Comment: FYI there are a lot of opinion pieces out there about why composition and dependency injection are better than inheritance.  The alternative way to structure this sort of code is that rather than extending an abstract class, the specific instances implement an interface declaring what properties/methods they need.  Then you would execute the functionality of the base class by taking the instance of the specific class as an argument in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think dependency injection would fulfill my needs, but you guided me to the right way. I managed to make it work using generics the way you explained in the answer, and also extending some of them by adding the attributes I needed to interact with.